# Jar File Not Functioning

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, ftp, executable-jar

I have been trying to get my program built into an excecutable .jar. The function of my program is to create a text file, place data in that text file, then upload the text file to my ftp server.

Inside eclipse, the program works perfectly with no errors or problems. Once I extract it to an excecutable .jar, the program does not display my JOptionPane.showMessageDialog() outputs and the text files are created and uploaded to the ftp server but the copy inside the ftp server has no data (the copy on my localmachine does have the data). When I ran it from the command prompt to check for errors, it ran perfectly.

The Class that is malfunctioning:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;

public class UploadKey {
    public void Send(String fileName) {
        FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        System.out.println("5");

        try {
            client.connect("host");
            client.login("username", "password");
            int replyCode = client.getReplyCode();
            System.out.println("6");
            if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(replyCode)) {
                client.disconnect();
                System.err.println("FTP server refused connection.");
                System.exit(1);
            }
            fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\" + fileName);
            System.out.println("7");
            client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            client.setFileTransferMode(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            System.out.println("8");
            client.storeFile(fileName, fis);
            System.out.println("9");
            fis.close();
            System.out.println("10");
            client.logout();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time,

Philip

EDIT: Solved, the .jar was being read as a javaw.exe instead of a java archive. Fixed via Jarfix application (http://johann.loefflmann.net/en/software/jarfix/index.html). Thank you all for your help.

Comment: 1) Add a few println statements to discover the program flow.  2) Print the stack trace in all catch clauses.

Comment: @Charles I tried both of these suggestions and I was unable to locate the problem with println statements because it ran without problems in the cmd prompt and sent the complete file to my server. It is only when I double click on the jar itself that it does not fully function.

Comment: Are you running it in Windows? If so, are you using a short-cut or are you double clicking on the actual file icon? Are you trying to read in jar resources as files and not resources? Is the program supposed to read in files, and if so, is its active user directory correct?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yes, I am running it in Windows 7. I am double clicking on the actual executable jar. I'm not sure what you mean by read the resources as files. The program is not supposed to read any files just write and upload a .txt

Comment: It sounds like authentication and/or user rights issue. Check the context you are using to execute this function.